# SSAS how to eliminate blank option in filter's hierarchy

Tags: filter, ssas

As the following snapshot shows, how could I eliminate or hide the blank option of the hierarchy? I know this is caused by null values in table but I do not want it to show up in the filter.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the data source view, you need to replace the table with a named query and then add a WHERE clause to the SELECT statement that will filter out these records that have a null value. However, be warned that if the fact table references any record that you filter out, you're going to have errors when you try to process your cube.

This link is for SSAS 2012, but it's the same process for any version of SSAS 2005 - SSAS 2008 R2: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175683